# bootstrap carousel - working on bootply, but not on the site

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have created a carousel which shows 6 logos and then advance, one. On Bootply, everything works fine: http://www.bootply.com/RkOFbrTp6F

When I add it into web page see here: http://url.kybernaut.cz/1e, it works but there the movement is more dynamic like the whole row is moved and loaded again advanced by one, not the slow and calm movement on the Bootply.

How can I fix it? The code looks identical. Here is the jquery code:

```
jQuery("#sponzoriCarousel").carousel({
          interval: 4000
        });

        jQuery('.carousel .item').each(function(){
          var next = jQuery(this).next();
          if (!next.length) {
            next = jQuery(this).siblings(':first');
          }
          next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo(jQuery(this));

          for (var i=0;i<4;i++) {
            next=next.next();
            if (!next.length) {
                next = jQuery(this).siblings(':first');
            }

            next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo(jQuery(this));
          }
        });
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Starting with 3.3.0 version](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/13074) Bootstrap uses `transform-3d` for carousel's transitions.

You are using Bootstrap 3.0.2 at the Bootsply. But your webpage has [a very strange version](http://demo.kybernaut.cz/missgolf/wp-content/themes/coni-pro/css/bootstrap.css?ver=3.1) of Bootstrap. It has `3.1` in the URL but it contains a fragment of the code from Bootstrap 3.3.0:

```
@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
  .carousel-inner > .item {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -moz-perspective: 1000;
    perspective: 1000;
  }
  .carousel-inner > .item.next,
  .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    left: 0;
  }
  .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
  .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    left: 0;
  }
  .carousel-inner > .item.next.left,
  .carousel-inner > .item.prev.right,
  .carousel-inner > .item.active {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

Try to delete this fragment from your `bootstrap.css` or use [the real Bootstrap 3.0.2](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css). I think it will help.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! So that means I need to add following css to my WP:

`.carousel-inner > .item.next,
  .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(16.66%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(16.66%, 0, 0);
    left: 0;
  }
  .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
  .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-16.66%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-16.66%, 0, 0);
    left: 0;
  }`

Comment: @kybernaut.cz Glad to be helpful. I've received an interesting experience how to combine the Bootstrap with Wordpress.